# How to understand this application of Green's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

I had difficulty in understanding the application of Green's Theorem for solving the boundary value problem [the full BVP is found here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nikolay-Kuznetsov-4/publication/241200615_NonUniqueness_in_Two-Dimensional_Water_Wave_Problems_Numerical_Evidence_and_Geometrical_Restrictions/links/0deec53516cc1311d7000000/NonUniqueness-in-Two-Dimensional-Water-Wave-Problems-Numerical-Evidence-and-Geometrical-Restrictions.pdf?origin=publication_detail).
$$\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x}-iK\phi=o(1) \,\, as \,\,x\to\infty\quad\quad(1)$$ where the potential function $\phi(x,y)$ satisfies Laplace equation $\nabla^2\phi(x,y)=0$. If apply Green's theorem to $\phi$ and its complex conjugate, the above equation (1) can be replaced by
$$\phi\to\infty,\,\, as \,\,x^2+y^2\to\infty.$$

Does it assume the condition that $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x}=iK\phi$?